# jTable moving to next specified column is interrupted

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to move through the table columns of selected row with below given approach:

```
//on Enter key press
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
 my_table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(enter, "nextColumn");

        my_table.getActionMap().put("nextColumn", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                if (itemSelected) {
                    //cost column
                    if (my_table.editCellAt(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 4)) {
                        System.out.println("column cost editing...");
                    }
                    itemSelected = false;
                } else {

                    if (my_table.isCellEditable(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 4)) {
                        //qty column 
                        System.out.println("column qty editing...");
                        my_table.editCellAt(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 6);
                        //It breaks from here
                    } else if (my_table.isCellEditable(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 6)) {
                        //free_qty column 
                        System.out.println("column free_qty editing...");
                        my_table.editCellAt(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 7);
                    } else if (my_table.isCellEditable(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 7)) {
                        //dis % column 
                        System.out.println("column dis % editing...");
                        my_table.editCellAt(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 8);
                    } else if (my_table.isCellEditable(my_table.getSelectedRow(), 8)) {
                        //free_qty column
                        System.out.println("column free_qty editing...");
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) my_table.getModel();
                        model.addRow(new Vector());
                        my_table.setRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

But when I press **Enter** key at `qty column` it does not move to next specified `free_qty column`.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

**UPDATE**

**Full compilable example**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Madushan
 */
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

// double click on the Code column to start
public class JTableCreatingDemo {

    private static boolean itemSelected = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {1, "PR000003", "Sample Item", "Grams", 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "#", "Code", "Name", "Unit", "Cost", "Prev. Bal.", "Qty", "Free Qty", "Dis %", "Dis amount", "Amount"
                }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }
        });

        KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(enter, "nextColumn");

        table.getActionMap().put("nextColumn", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                if (itemSelected) {
                    //cost column
                    if (table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4)) {
                        System.out.println("column cost editing...");
                    }
                    itemSelected = false;
                } else {

                    if (table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(), 4)) {
                        //qty column 
                        System.out.println("column qty editing...");
                        table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 6);
                    } else if (table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(), 6)) {
                        //free_qty column 
                        System.out.println("column free_qty editing...");
                        table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 7);
                    } else if (table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(), 7)) {
                        //dis % column 
                        System.out.println("column dis % editing...");
                        table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 8);
                    } else if (table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(), 8)) {
                        //free_qty column
                        System.out.println("column free_qty editing...");
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                        model.addRow(new Vector());
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I updated the problem GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
} else {

    if (table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(), 4)) {
```

Well the above condition is always true, since you always start the check at the 4th column.

What you really want to do is create a loop that iterates through all the columns in the table, starting at `table.getSelectedColumn() + 1` until you find the next editable column.